# how can i slide div's programmatically in Ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

how can i slide div's in ionic framework pro grammatically using some flag? For ex.
if i have two div's

```
<div>
 div 1
</div>

<div>
 div 2
</div>
```

i want to slide these two div's one by one , based on some flag .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [SlideBox](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/) and then with the [$ionicSlideBoxDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/)

If you can use selectors to identify the div, you can then call $ionicSlideBoxDelegate's slide(to, [speed]). method.

Hope this helps